# Добавить код HTML после ссылки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, ссылки

На веб-страницах сайта существуют ссылки на архивы для загрузки файла.

**Ссылки такого вида:**

```
<a title="" href="http://site.ru/downloads/soft.zip">bestsoft</a>
```

Нужно после каждой такой ссылки вставить тег HTML, например `<hr />`. Т.е. после закрывающего тега `</a>` стразу должен быть тег `<hr />`.

**Вот как нужно:**

```
<a title="" href="http://site.ru/downloads/soft.zip">bestsoft</a><hr />
```

**Что я делал:**

Я нашел на веб-страницах такие ссылки по расширению файла, регуляркой.

```
$html = preg_replace('/<a[^>]+.zip[^"]*">(.*?)<\/a>$/', '<hr />', $html);

return $html;
```

Но ссылки заменились тегом `<hr />`.

**Вопрос:**

Какой правильный код, который добавит тег HTML сразу после ссылок на архив с расширением файлов .zip, .rar, .7-zip?

Comment: `preg_replace('~<a\s[^>]+\.zip[^"]*">.*?</a>$~', '$0<hr />', $html);`

Comment: никаких изменений нет

Comment: [Это у Вас нет. А у нас есть.](https://ideone.com/0ugeio)

Comment: да, есть, странно, буду искать ошибку. СПС

Comment: нашел ошибку, так работает: `$text = preg_replace('/<a[^>]+.zip[^"]*">(.*?)<\/a>/', '$0<hr />', $text);` можно вместо слеша тильду. Чуть голову не сломал об регулярку. Еще, редактор автоматом ставит тег br перед hr. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью рабочий пример:

```
function addhtml_forlink( $text ) {

   $html = '<hr />';
   $text = preg_replace('/<a[^>]+\.(zip|rar|gz|tar)[^"]*">(.*?)<\/a>/',"$0$html", $text);

return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a title="" href="<?php echo 'you link'; ?>"><?php echo 'you name'; ?></a><hr />
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace('/(<a.+?\.zip".+?<\/a>)/', '$1<hr />', $subject);`